# We need a "play" button in the replayer chessboard

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

I need a "play" button in the replayer chessboard. Often, I want to watch the whole game, without having to press a button 100 times to replay 50 moves.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to press a button 100 times to play through 50 moves.

You can use the scroll button on the mouse to move rapidly forwards and backwards through the game. This is much better than a "play" button because it stops when you want it to and has a reverse gear.

Comment: Tablets, cell phones...